# Terminate Angular2 Webworker Application

Tags: angular, web-worker

I've got my angular2 (2.4.1) application running on platform-webworker.

When someone logs out of the application, they are redirected to a login page on a different sub-domain, but same primary domain.

Their authentication is revoked but it does not appear that this redirection alone terminates the background web-worker.  Even more strange is that ngOnDispose doesn't appear to have been called on all of the controllers that no longer exist, and all the services are still running.

Anyone have ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is I'm an idiot. - not sure how to delete the question!